# What is the standard measure of fit quality for least absolute deviation regression (the analog of $R^2$)

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, least-absolute-deviations

When one runs an OLS regression, one often prefers to look at $R^2$ rather than the mean squared error, though both measure goodness of fit. $R^2$ is dimensionless and has some advantageous properties: for example, it's related to other important quantities such as correlation, and it behaves nicely if you scale or translate your data.

When I run an LAD regression, I can look at the sum of absolute errors or the mean absolute error or something. But is there a different statistic, something like $R^2$, that people tend to look at instead?

Comment: I've seen in the past measures like $\sum |\text{residual}|/ \sum |\text{ response} - \text{median of response}|$ but no-one is obliged to take them too seriously.